# Wordpress blog is now showing Install page ? the db is still there and wp-config has correct details

Tags: wordpress

I am not sure what happened but I just looked at my wordpress site and it is showing the install page /wp-admin/install.php instead of showing the blog content.

1. I checked wp-config and it has correct database details
2. The database also exist and has all the content

What is going wrong and how can I fix this ?

Comment: Check `wp-options` table in database and check your `siteurl` and `home` links are right OR not?

Comment: if possible, using a debug tool like Xdebug to debug function is_blog_installed() in wp-includes/functions.php

Comment: database details correct - but also the wp_prefix ? ( a lot of people forget that .. )

Comment: In my case my wp-config.php file was hacked. I just restaured the original version of it and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, this occurs when one or more of the database tables are corrupt — wp_options in particular.

Try issuing [`check table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html) and [`repair table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html) statements accordingly.

Comment: Try this, if worst comes to worst backup the table with all the information you need and import it into a new table

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, thanks I repaired the table and now it is working fine

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was "$table_prefix" in wp-config.php. Once I created the new one:

**New** DB: `$table_prefix  = 'wp02_';`

**Old** DB: `$table_prefix  = 'wp_';`

hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: @tom, thank you for edits, I will keep in mind these points in future.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, WP was installed on a (free) shared hosting provider, with limited resources. There is a limit on the traffic to/from the database. So each day, after a lot of traffic, the database replies with error:

```
user has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource
```

and WP shows the install page.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me all the time when I make too many changes. The hosting provider just shows this page for about half an hour and then I can continue working again. Try not having too many page editors open at the same time because they autosave every now and then, even if you don't do anything on them. But if it's doing this because of your visitors, you should probably upgrade to a stronger hosting plan.